# CSS3 animation can't be called by javascript

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am doing some tests in order to later animate a website and i want to be able to make a button bounce when its clicked on however i cannot seem to get it to work. THe animation for the heading works fine on page load.

This is my entire code

```
<head>

    <script>    
        function click(test){
            test.style.webkitAnimationName = 'bounce';
            test.style.webkitAnimationDuration = '3s';

             setTimeout(function() {
                 test.style.webkitAnimationName = '';
             }, 4000);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
            -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes slidein {
            0%  {
                margin-left: 100%;
                width: 300%; 
            }

            100%{
                margin-left: 0%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
            0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                transform: translateY(0);
            }

            40% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
                transform: translateY(-30px);
            }

            60% {
                -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
                transform: translateY(-15px);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <title>Success message</title>
</head>
<body>
    <H1> You entered all the data required </H1>
    <button onclick="click(this)">amg4aeorg;ji</button>

</body>
```

can someone please tell me why it isn't working, thank you in advance

**EDIT**

Ive done some testing and found out the the javascript function isn't actually running, anybody know why? thx

Answer (score 1):

Make a CSS class to wrap the animation, then add that CSS **class name** to the element.

```
test.setAttribute('class','bounceThis');
```

CSS:

```
.bounceThis {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: bounce 3s ease-out;
    animation: bounce 3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce { ... etc.... }
```

Comment: THis will probably work, but can you help me with my new problem? per edit at the bottom of the question